# SSIS package to process whole SSAS database

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, ssas, cube

we are using SSIS packages to process Cubes in SQL Server 2008 R2 Analysis Services. Until now we have been using an Analysis Services Processing Task in the package and have been manually adding all Cube and Dimension objects to the processing queue in that task. This also means we have to adjust the package when we add Dimensions to a Cube or Cubes to the SSAS DB.

But now we need an SSIS package that will process the whole SSAS **database** selected, so that we can modify the Cube later on, possibly adding Dimensions, without having to modify the package as well.

In SQL Server Management Studio it is possible to right click an SSAS database and select "Process..." but for the corresping SSIS task, I could not find out how to do this.

Is there any way to process a whole SSAS database in an SSIS package?

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm confused as to why you can't use the SSIS Analysis Services Processing Task.  I believe you have to option to select a database in the processing settings. You can choose then entire database rather than choosing individual cubes or dimensions on that database. Just make sure the Type says database.

[image]

I have also used the XMLA answer provided by @Meff and it works fine as well.

Comment: Oh that's much simpler than my answers :) I haven't used this component for years, with partitioning and such I find I usually need more fine control than the component gives, but this should be perfect for @cmenke.

Comment: Thank you, I am amazed that we did not find this on our own... going to have to a word with the "specialists"... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use AMO, you would need to include the Microsoft.AnalysisServices reference to a SSIS script task and provide the variable values. This way doesn't lock you to the database Id but is slightly more complex:

```
   string cubeConnectionString = Dts.Variables["User::CubeConnectionString"].Value.ToString();
    string databaseName = Dts.Variables["User::DatabaseName"].Value.ToString();

    Server server = new Server();
    server.Connect(cubeConnectionString);

    Database database = server.Databases.FindByName(databaseName);
    database.Process(ProcessType.ProcessFull);

    server.Disconnect();
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: We try to avoid the use of Script components for ease of maintenance, but I will keep this in mind in case we ever need a more universal solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you go to process the whole database, before you click 'OK', you should see a "Script" button in the top-left of the process window. This will generate the processing XMLA to a new window.

Now take that processing XMLA and use it in an "Analysis Services Execute DDL" control-flow component.

Be careful with cube re-deployments as you'll see the XMLA uses the Id not the name of the database.